# Call str_replace() on all values while recursively traversing a multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, replace

I basically want to use `str_replace()` all values of a multidimensional array. I can't seem to work out how I would do this for multidimensional arrays. I get a little stuck when the value is an array -- it just seems to be in a neverending loop. I'm new to PHP so examples would be helpful.

```
function _replace_amp($post = array(), $new_post = array())
{
    foreach($post as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
           unset($post[$key]);
           $this->_replace_amp($post, $new_post);
        }
        else
        {
            // Replace :amp; for & as the & would split into different vars.
            $new_post[$key] = str_replace(':amp;', '&', $value);
            unset($post[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $new_post;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've come up with so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wrong and will put you into a never-ending loop:

```
$this->_replace_amp($post, $new_post);
```

You don't need to send `new_post` as an argument, and you also want to *make the problem smaller* for each recursion. Change your function to something like this:

```
function _replace_amp($post = array())
{
    $new_post = array();
    foreach($post as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
           unset($post[$key]);
           $new_post[$key] = $this->_replace_amp($value);
        }
        else
        {
            // Replace :amp; for & as the & would split into different vars.
            $new_post[$key] = str_replace(':amp;', '&', $value);
            unset($post[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $new_post;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

...What's wrong with [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)?

```
<?php
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

Comment: Because in your eggsample if you add a nested level: `$fruits = [ 'sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon', 'its_not' => ['recursive_depth'] ];` in that case you are not getting the correct key for 'its_not' - it gives you `0`, expected `its_not` -- Or as one has said ***THIS FUNCTION ONLY VISITS LEAF NODES*** (php.net -- lol he capslocked it)