# preg_replace strings "data[key1][key2][]" in "[data][key1][key2]"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace or extend the following sample strings not arrays in php

```
"data" in "[data]"
"data[key]" in "[data][key]"
"data[key1][key2]" in "[data][key1][key2]"
"data[key1][key2][]" in "[data][key1][key2]"
"data[]" in "[data]"
```

and so on.
I tried something with preg_replace but i couldt not find the correct pattern

Comment: Wouldn't this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088687/recursive-loop-for-multidimenional-arrays

Comment: no it wouldn't sot that are strings not arrays

Comment: Your question is not very clear as to what kind of transformation you are trying to do to the strings. What do you mean by "in"? Are you trying to take the string on the left of "in" and turn it _into_ the string on the right? Are you somehow trying to find the string on the left and replace it in the string on the right, or visa versa?

Answer (score 0):

As the question stands now, you basically want to transform all the words that aren't enclosed in brackets to enclosed one, and remove the empty brackets.

In php, this could be done in two steps in one function !

```
$string = 'data
data[key]
data[key1][key2]
data[key1][key2][]
data[]';

$string = preg_replace(
    array('/(?<!\[)(\b\w+\b)(?!\])/', '/\[\]/'),
    array('[$1]', ''),
    $string);
echo $string;
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\[)(\b\w+\b)(?!\])
   ^       ^      ^--- Negative lookahead, check if there is no ] after the word
   ^       ^--- \b\w+\b
   ^             ^  ^--- \w+ matches the occurence of [a-zA-Z0-9_] once or more
   ^             ^--- \b "word boundary" check http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html
   ^--- Negative lookbehind, check if there is no [ before the word

   \[\] This basically just match []
```

[Online PHP demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RSBbBB).